# Better "left / substring" solution for <%# Container.DataItem %>

Tags: asp.net

This little asp.net code has some drawbacks. 
If the itemrow is empty, it will fail.
If the item tends to be shorter than 10 chars, you already know.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbnHistory" CommandName="lbnHistory" 
  CommandArgument="'<%# Container.DataItem %>' 
  Text='<%# ((string)Container.DataItem).ToString().Substring(5,10) %>' 
  runat="server">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

I'm also available to solve this with the repeatercommandevent i use for this task.
For simplification, I want it filled from a comma separated string.
The task itself is so simple and not worth creating and iterating a strong type.

What do you think?

Comment: Just a note to a few: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "someField") %> = strong type.

Comment: Just note this isn't a custom class, but it seems this repeater is iterating a string collection...

Comment: @Matías its a "long" string which splits into rows with .Split[';']. The string are growing due to some actions which reloads the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whops, I think I was to deep into other thoughs.
You just have to create a public method and wrap it into..

For the sake of clarify..
 <%# SampleTruncing((string)Container.DataItem) %>